# How to pass multiple parameters to a query in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to pass multiple parameters to a query in Android.
I do the following:

```
String final QUERY = "SELECT TA.ID FROM TAB TA LEFT JOIN PROP P ON P.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN LOC L ON L.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN TIME T ON T.ID = TA.ID  WHERE (COALESCE(LONG,?) - ?) * (COALESCE(LONG,?) - ?) + (COALESCE(LAT,?) - ?)  * (COALESCE(LAT,?) - ?) <=COALESCE(VALUE,0)*COALESCE(VALUE,0)  AND ? BETWEEN  COALESCE(BEGIN,0) AND COALESCE(END, 123456)";
    String[] args= {"" + val1, "" + val2, "" + val3, "" + val4, "" + val5, "" val6, "" + val7, "" + val8, "" + val9};
    cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY,args);
```

But it retruns an empty cursor. I tried the query in the shell, it works. How to implement it in the code?

**EDIT**:
I found another way to do it:

```
QUERY = "SELECT TA.ID FROM TAB TA LEFT JOIN PROP P ON P.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN LOC L ON L.ID = TA.ID LEFT JOIN TIME T ON T.ID = TA.ID  WHERE (COALESCE(LONG," + val1+ " ) - " + val2 + " ) * (COALESCE(LONG," + val3 + " ) - " + val4 + " ) + (COALESCE(LAT," + val5 + " ) - " +  val6 + ")  * (COALESCE(LAT," +  val7 + " ) - " + val8 + ") <=COALESCE(VALUE,0)*COALESCE(VALUE,0)  AND" +  val9 + " BETWEEN  COALESCE(BEGIN,0) AND COALESCE(END, 123456)";
  cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY,null);
```

Comment: does cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY,null); return anything?

Comment: No, It returns an empty cursor too.

Comment: are you check in `sqlite browser`

Answer (score 0):

You have done some mistakes and imprecision.
To increase performance it's better if you use:

```
String.valueOf(valX);
```

Then if you take a look to android [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) documentation you'll see that the method rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs) accepts the sql plus the selectionArgs those aren't your whereArgs.